# Why is the gradient of the expenditure function equal to the hicksian vector?

Tags: microeconomics

I'm reading MWG Microeconomic Theory, and I'm stuck on why the gradient of the expenditure function equals the hicksian vector at a point P. I'm trying to understand it from the duality perspective. I drew some pictures to help with my geometric intuition. So the problem is we want to minimize expenditure for a given amount of utility.
$$\min_{x\geq0}\  x\cdot p=w$$
$$st\ u(x) \geq \bar{u} $$
So from the duality pov the constraint gives us a convex set as shown in graph 2. Now for any P (I used two) we can use the support function which is the expenditure function (graph 3) to find a $w$ such that  $w \geq x\cdot p$ creates a line (hyperplane is higher dimensions) were the entire convex set is greater than the line. Also the only $x$ in the convex set that is also on the line is the vector $x$ that satisfies the expenditure minimizing problem (assuming strict convexity).

So 1 is everything I said correct? and 2 why are the $x's$ (Green vectors) in graph 2 that satisfies the emp equal to the $x's$ (Green vectors) in graph 3 that are the gradients of the expenditure function at those points?

[image]